# MS SQL dataType for time in this format HH.MM.SS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know with `fractional` and `precision` values I could use to create a column of type `time` in this format HH:MM:SS when creating a DATABASE table thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't generally, be thinking of `date`s, `time`s, or `datetime`s as being stored in any particular string format (they're actually stored internally in binary or numeric formats). Treating such data values as strings is one of the largest sources of errors and problems.

Comment: Thanks Damien for your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIME(0) would give you a time with no fractional precision.  The following URL has a chart that will help.

[SQL Server Time Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)